# Searching in multiple category + URL hierarchy in real estate WordPress site

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, permalinks

I'm doing a project, which reminds a lot like every other real estate site. The site provides information from different buildings (we shall call them now on). On landing page we have a search form, which is planned to work like this:

**Form is asking this data**

- Location *| Data about location is in the cpt post (ACF)*
- List Type *| Buy or Rent (Both are own category)*
- Building type *| Beach house, Flat etc. (Categories under "Building type" category)*
- Size *(Only in page /rent/. Data by ACF)*
- Prize *(Only in page /rent/. Data by ACF)*

**What should happen after user does the query**

IF the user clicked type=buy , we go url domain/buy/
IF the user clicked listtype=buy + Location , we go url domain/buy/location/
IF the user clicked type=buy + buildingtype=flat + Location , we go url domain/buy/location/buildingtype

1. How do I approach this? I'm already going wrong by using only one custom type (building) or should I do multiple CPTs like buy + rent?
2. Should I be using categories vs. tags?

Comment: Use taxonomies for this... quicker queries and easier to just toggle a series of checkboxes in the back end.

Comment: Well if I add custom taxonomies to articles - how still I approach this in URLs?

Comment: You can use query strings or write your own endpoints.  https://wpmudev.com/blog/building-customized-urls-wordpress/ & https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Or you can use the parent->child taxonomy relationships.